# Parent and Part Relationship Cost Calculation using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Child and Parent relationship table with cost.
I need to roll up the child part costs into parent.
Attached is the image for the table.
Reqd. column shows the cost rollup I need.
But I am not able to do it using sql queries.
Also, recursive queries won't help since total line items are more than 100k.
Any suggestion or ideas will be very helpful.

[image: Parent Child relationship]

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: I don't understand how the "rolling up" should work - can you please define the business logic more clearly?

Comment: Hi, e.g Parent Id 1 has 2,3 and 4. But 2 also has 3,4. So for 2 total cost is (3+1), and 3 has 4,5,6 3(5+3+1). that's what I meant by rolling up. Sorry if i used incorrect term.

Comment: It seems it's not a typical hierarchy table?  F.e. 4 is a child of 3 and 2 and 1.

Comment: @LukStorms, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you are saying you can't use CTE & SQL query. So what technical base do you want to rely on?

By SQL it is totally doable with the functions of aggregate & joins

EDIT:

Without your schema, try to adapt this query for your table :

```
SELECT j.ID, j.Parent_ID, SUM(t.Cost)
FROM MyTableCost as t
INNER join MyTableCost AS j on j.ID = t.Parent_ID
GROUP BY j.ID, j.Parent_ID;
```

Comment: I need to do it using Sql query, CTE is good, but not recursive because actually It has 100k rows.

Comment: Is it possible to have the database schema?

Comment: I can't share the actual schema, as I don't have access. Apologies.

Comment: Last column Reqd. Cost is what I need using first 3 columns.

Comment: Check my edit in my post

Comment: I am not getting any result

Comment: Share your request please

Comment: Hi Mehdi, I am sorry, but I am running it on another server. If it helps, my output doesn't show correct values for Parent Id 1 and 2. For instance parent id 1 is showing sum(t.cost) value as only 5, instead of 14 ( the sum up cost of 2,3 and 4).

Comment: I am using exactly the same query what you shared.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One self-join seems to be enough.
But I don't see the logic for rolling up id 4.

> ```
> select t0.parent_id, t0.part_id, t0.cost
> , coalesce(sum(t1.cost), t0.cost) as reqd_cost
> from your_weird_hierarchy_table t0
> left join your_weird_hierarchy_table t1
>   on t1.parent_id = t0.part_id
> group by t0.parent_id, t0.part_id, t0.cost;
> ```
>
> ```
> parent_id | part_id |   cost | reqd_cost
> --------: | ------: | -----: | --------:
>         1 |       2 | 1.0000 |    4.0000
>         1 |       3 | 2.0000 |    9.0000
>         1 |       4 | 1.0000 |    1.0000
>         2 |       3 | 3.0000 |    9.0000
>         2 |       4 | 1.0000 |    1.0000
>         3 |       4 | 5.0000 |    5.0000
>         3 |       5 | 3.0000 |    3.0000
>         3 |       6 | 1.0000 |    1.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2aef976c5891099dc47f4023cae0abe7)*

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for me. I agree it's a "weird_hierarchy_table".

Comment: I updated table to add hierarchy and now it looks like this. Can you please suggest how would calculate cost now ?

PARENT PART LEVEL PRIMARY_COST
1 3 1 $1.00
1 2 1 $2.00
1 1A 1 $3.00
2 4 2 $12.00
2 1B 2 $5.00
2 1C 2 $3.00

Comment: I refuse. You haven't changed the question. And then should explain what that level has to do with it.

Comment: Hi LukStorms, when I tried this on actual data, cost were not rolling up correctly. I thought if the hierarchy specify the level, it would be easier to calculate the cost.